# Proof that the series $1 * 1 + 2 * 2 + 3 * 3 ... n * n$ is $O(n^3)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

Is this summation correct?:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i \cdot i)$

How would I go about proving that the statement is $O(n^3)$?

Comment: Where is an equation and where is the recurrence?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just thought that this was similar to recurrence equations that I've seen. What would be the proper question to ask?

Comment: We have $(n+1)^3-n^3 = 3n^2+3n+1$, hence
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 \leq \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left((i+1)^3-i^3\right)\le\frac{(n+1)^3}{3}=O(n^3). $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's $$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},$$ which we can get by the telescopic sum.

Comment: I am interested in your telecopic sum...

Comment: @amsmath Use $(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+1$ and $1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$

Comment: Ah, thanks. Got it.

Comment: I realize now ( after purchasing the class textbook and spending 5 minutes in the appendix) that this question is the Sum of Squares. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Godron629 You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Given that you only need $O(n^3)$, a possible answer would be that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n n^2 \leq n\times n^2 = n^3.
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2\ge\sum_{i=2}^ni(i-1)=\frac13\sum_{i=2}^n[(i+1)i(i-1)-i(i-1)(i-2)]=\frac{n(n^2-1)}3\ge\frac13n^3.
$$

Comment: I think it's not enough. We can get also that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni^2<n^{1000}$

Comment: "A trivial answer"  maybe to you, but not to many users on this site: it comes across as arrogant.

Comment: I think it's a total wrong answer. @Alberto Debernardi The down vote is not mine.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg No, it is completely correct. Look up the $O$-notation.

Comment: @amsmath See please my previous comment.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I did. So what? He proved that there is a positive constant such that the expression is $\le Cn^3$.

Comment: @amsmath We need to prove also that i'ts $\geq C_1n^3$.

Comment: The $O$-notation stands for an upper estimate, not lower.

Comment: That's right. Therefore, I wrote "Look up...".

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think you've confused $O(n^3)$ with $\Theta(n^3)$. The answer is correct, if extremely terse....

Comment: @user296602 It's a deal of the  definition. Here, if everyone said so,  then I with everyone, but I don't like it.